# MODx MIGX setting browser directory context

Tags: modx

I'm using MIGX to aggregate info for product entries. By default, the MODX file browser opens to directory "Files", where I'd like it to open to "Files->assets->img->products". Do I need a snippet to do this, and what variable would I set? (Or better yet, where is this type of info to be found in the rtfm?)

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to create a new media source, or use the default one, and change the default browse directory for that media source. You can then restrict a specific user group to the media source or let everyone use it by default.

Comment: Well, spoke too soon. I'm able to create a new media source, I'm able to set the basePath and baseUrl appropriately, and associate the new media source to the migx tv, but the default browse directory still comes up set to Filesystem (although at least now, I can select the correct directory context via the MODX Browser pulldown).